# How to apply filter to new order emails only (wordpress, woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need help applying the following filter to woocommerce admin new order emails only. I've tried a few things but cant get it working.

```
**function filter_woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity( $qty_display, $item ) {
$product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );
$product_id = $product->get_id();

if ( $product_id == 6960 ) {
    $qty_display = $qty_display * 2;
}

return $qty_display; 
}; 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', 'filter_woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes against some things ive read but this code is working for me

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'add_order_instruction_email', 11, 4 );

function add_order_instruction_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

   remove_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', 'filter_woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', 10, 2 );

  }; 

function filter_woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity( $qty_display, $item ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );
    $product_id = $product->get_id();

if ( $product_id == 6960 ) {
    $qty_display = $qty_display * 2;
}
    if ( $product_id == 6912 ) {
    $qty_display = $qty_display * 2;
}
    if ( $product_id == 6861 ) {
    $qty_display = $qty_display * 2;
}

return $qty_display; 
}; 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', 'filter_woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to WPSE.
`$item` is an instance of `WC_Order_Item` and not an array, so it's not possible get the product_id from the order item object like that (`$item['product_id']`).
I suggest using WooCommerce standard methods as below.

#### Update:

`woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity` action filter does not provide an argument to know if it's an admin or customer email. To do so, we need to do a trick.

I would hook a function to `woocommerce_email_order_details` action to find out whether if the current email is to be sent to an admin and save it in a constant to modify the quantity later based on it's value. Woocommerce hooks it's function with the priority of 10 to this hook, so we need a lower priority.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', function( $order, $sent_to_admin )
{
    if ( $sent_to_admin && ! defined('TST_ADMIN_EMAIL') ) {
        define( 'TST_ADMIN_EMAIL', true );
    }
}, 9, 2 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', 'tst_filter_woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', 10, 2 );
function tst_filter_woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity( $qty_display, $item )
{
    if (
        defined('TST_ADMIN_EMAIL')
        && true === TST_ADMIN_EMAIL
        && 'line_item' === $item->get_type()
    ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $product_id = $product->get_id();

        if ( $product_id == 6960 ) {
            $qty_display = $qty_display * 2;
        }
    }

    return $qty_display; 
};
```

Comment: Thanks although the code works fine... just need it to apply to new order admin emails and not customer emails.